# Can not use cifs mount anymore

Tags: 13.10, cifs

I upgraded from 11.04 to 13.10, but my cifs mount does not work anymore.

Comment: How did you try to mount it ? What error message did you get ?

Comment: Did you have package cifs-utils installed?  Needed for 13.04 and after I think.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks

I found the solution.
There seems to be a change in syntax. In 11.04 I coud mount using

```
mount -t cifs //jupiter/qm        /utdnetdrive/qm       
-o rw,_netdev,username=DOMAIN/USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,uid=peter,gid=users
,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

and I just had to change this to

```
mount -t cifs //jupiter/qm        /utdnetdrive/qm       
-o rw,_netdev,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,domain=DOMAIN,uid=peter,gid=users
,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

NOW IT WORKS!!
Thansk for your support
Peter S.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution, And i'm using this and Its work for me, [Step by Step Samba Mounting](http://www.linuxmental.com/blog/2013/11/09/how-to-configure-a-automount-samba-share-in-fstab-while-every-boot-ubuntu/)

Install the Client package

Create a Directory Anywere , Here i have Created a Directory name Samba

edit the fstab and give the entry

This is the Syntax What you Need to Enter in fstab

//server/share /pathto/mountpoint cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=shareuser,gid=sharegroup 0 0

Then Create a Credential file , if you have Setted the Workgroup mention it there in Credential if not Don't need it , just enter the username and password

change the Created Credential file mode to access only by root to 600

Use the Command Sudo mount -a to get mount the samba share